# How to use change() And keydown() at a Time

Tags: javascript

When I Press 'Enter' Both methods are call simultaneously But I want To call only one method which display Enter.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSerialCodePopUp" runat="server" CssClass="txtSerialCodePopUp form-control" placeholder="Enter SerialNo"></asp:TextBox>


$('.txtSerialCodePopUp').keydown(function(e)
        {
            if(e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                alert("Enter");
                return false;
            }
        });

        $('.txtSerialCodePopUp').change(function()
        {
              alert("Change");
              return false;
        });
```

Here, txtSerialCodePopUp is Textbox

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce it:( https://jsfiddle.net/9bp2v6bw/

Answer (score 2):

use jquery.on for multiple events triggering 
like below :

```
$('.txtSerialCodePopUp').on('keydown change ', function(e) {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to stop propagation of the event. You can use

```
 $('.txtSerialCodePopUp').keydown(function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
     alert("Enter");

     // Stop propagation of the event
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
   }
 });

 $('.txtSerialCodePopUp').change(function() {
   alert("Change");
   return false;
 });
```

You can find the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Here is an implementation of this: http://output.jsbin.com/dikidasuhu

This is especially useful if you want to call another function when pressing "enter" than when changing the input of the field.

Comment: After Adding event.stopImmediatePropagation(); Method Called Twice.